# difference between warning and a fault in Linear Technologies chip

Tags: power-supply, components

My team is executing a design and using LTM 4677. They asked to write software to read the status of the device. The documentation for it quite comprehensive, but what I can't figure out is the difference between a fault and a warning in this device. Can someone help me out on this? [Here is the link to the documentation](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4677f.pdf) is you need it.

Answer (score 1):

In general a warning means something could go wrong if unchecked, and fault means something has gone wrong. A short circuit of the output would be a fault.

Take the LTM4677 internal temperature fault and warning as an example. If a temperature warning (130C) is given it means that the device is working, but EEPROM access is disabled. At 160C the fault threshold is triggered, and the output is disabled.